# How many CSS formatting contexts are there?

Tags: css

I'm reading CSS2.1 spec. I know "block formatting context", "inline formatting context", "table/grid/flex formatting context".

I want to know, how many kinds of "formatting context" are there? Is there a complete list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, a "formatting context" is simply an area in which descendant boxes of a certain kind (e.g. block, inline, flex-item) are laid out (or formatted) in normal flow.

In CSS2.1, there are only two kinds of formatting context: block and inline. Both of these are described as appropriate in [section 9.4](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#normal-flow). There is no such thing as a table formatting context, at least not as defined by CSS2.1; instead it simply says that [a table box establishes a block formatting context](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#model), however its contents are laid out in a tabular fashion.

Other types of formatting context are defined in their respective CSS3 modules, so there may not be an exhaustive list. That said, some examples include:

- [Flexbox](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox): flex containers establish flex formatting contexts.
- [Grid Layout](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout): grid containers establish grid formatting contexts.

Comment: The OP posted a follow up question which I answered at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16936297/when-does-a-box-establish-a-inline-formatting-context  If you have time, could you review and comment.  Thank you.

Comment: Table formatting context was first introduced in [errata section](http://www.w3.org/Style/css2-updates/REC-CSS2-20110607-errata.html#s.9.4) of CSS2.1 (in August 2012), and then incorporated into [CSS2.2 draft](https://drafts.csswg.org/css/visuren.html#normal-flow).

Comment: Already have [`table formatting context`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/tables.html#table-layout) in `CSS2.2`.