# When does a box establish an inline formatting context?

Tags: css

I read that a block formatting context is created in some cases from [MDN:Block formatting context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Block_formatting_context).

I wonder when does a box establish an inline formatting context?

One case I know is: when a block container box contains only inline-level boxes.

Comment: What is the question and how does it relate to a coding problem?

Comment: I'm reading css2.1 spec chapter 9. The question is not directly related to coding. Someone please help me to move the question to the place it belongs...I don't know the right place to ask this question.sorry

Comment: This is a question that refers to a fundamental aspect of CSS.  It is relevant to many CSS questions posed on SO and deserves some attention.

Comment: People seem to down vote just about anything these days - fair question and good answer @MarcAudet

Comment: Questions about the CSS box model are on topic for SO. Also, what Marc Audet said.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To answer your question, I reread [Section 9.2.1 of the CSS 2.1 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-boxes).

Based on my reading, you have your answer: the inline formatting context is triggered when a block container box contains only inline elements.

In contrast to a block formatting context that can be triggered explicitly (for example, setting `overflow: hidden` to a block-level element), an inline formatting context cannot be triggered explicitly.

Inline formatting contexts appear to always exist as descendant block boxes within a "principal block-level box", and these descendant block boxes may be anonymous.

I offer the following description as a mental model for understanding block/inline formatting contexts.

A block-level element (e.g. a `<div>`) fulfills two responsibilities: one, positioning, and two, content formatting.

When dealing with positioning, a block-level element acts as a "block-level box".

When dealing with formatting, a block-level element acts as a "block container box".

Acting as a "block-level box", the block-element behaves according to the type of positioning (static, absolute, relative, fixed) specified by the `position` property.

Acting as a "block container box", the block-element establishes a block-formatting context if the block-element has at least one child block-level element.  If all the child elements are inline-level boxes, then an inline-formatting context is established.

If the "block container box" contains text and block elements, then the text is treated as being contained in one or more anonymous block-level boxes, and a block-formatting context is established.

**Aside**
The CSS spec is not exactly light reading.  I have reread Chapters 9 and 10 several times and I have yet to come up with a plain-English translation.

Comment: Yes; to exemplify: given `<div>text</div>`, 1) the `div` block box contains only inline content, so it creates an inline formatting context for the text, and 2) the text itself resides in an anonymous inline box that participates in this inline formatting context.

Comment: And given `<div>inline<p>block</div>`, 1) the `div` block box contains inline content as well as a `p` block box, so it creates an anonymous block box for the inline content alongside the `p`, and 2) this anonymous block box creates an inline formatting content for the text. This means the inline content resides in an anonymous inline box that is nested in an anonymous block box that is the first child of the `div`, and a sibling to the `p`.

Comment: @BoltClock, Thanks! Example in your second comment is exactly what I am thinking about!